# Is a GKVoiceChat example available for the iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am seeking a GKVoiceChat example for the iPhone SDK in 4.0 or later. It will surely help with my iPhone game.

Comment: This question is, unfortunately, off-topic. The official close reason is: _It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Game Kit samples I've seen that include GKVoiceChat.

1. Search for GCPing in the Apple dev forums.  (I'm not posting a link because it's not clear the author wants a public link).  This sample is clear and basic, but demonstrates a wide range of working Game Kit multiplayer concepts.  Search back over 'all' time, and look for the 'GCPing WWDC2010 - Updated for iOS 4 GM Seed' post.
2. multiplayer Pong client. Found [here](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=72325).

Haven't looked into sample 2 much yet, but it looks pretty good.

Comment: Woah. thanks dude. Posted this like a year ago , and was still looking for an answer.

Comment: Yay!  Thanks.  My first accepted answer (my first *any* answer) on stackoverflow.  Was kinda hoping you were still looking. ;) I was looking for some help with GKVoiceChat myself (got it working, but sorta conflicting w/ my current audio setup) and came across both sample 2 and your question.

Comment: Lol. I'm just simply looking for a way to communicate between two devices with the bluetooth add on.

Comment: Meaning direct peer to peer, or something to do with a bluetooth headset?  The GKVoiceChat connection requires an active GKMatch, so it has to at least go through Apple's Game Center server to start.

Comment: Yea, thats what I meant peer to peer.