# Opening a match with a stranger to hold a video chat

Tags: game-center, gamekit

Hullo,
I would like to establish a voice chat between a user and a taxi driver and I selected GameKit as a solution, yet it seems the two users need to be first friends and that is qyuite a nuisance I think I may somewhat solve.

Yet when I open the voice chat with:

```
-(void)initializeVoiceChat:(GKMatch*) matchTaxi{
NSError* error=nil;
AVAudioSession* audioSession=[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
if (error){
    NSLog(@"AN error occurred while starting audio session: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
GKVoiceChat *talkTaxi = [matchTaxi voiceChatWithName:@"redTeam"];
talkTaxi.active=YES;
talkTaxi.playerStateUpdateHandler=^(NSString* playerId, GKVoiceChatPlayerState state){
    switch (state) {
        case GKVoiceChatPlayerSpeaking:
            [self showSpeakingPlayer: playerId];
            break;
        case GKVoiceChatPlayerSilent:
            [self stopShowSpeakingPlayer: playerId];
        default:
            break;
    }
};
[talkTaxi start];
}
```

The block in playerStateUpdateHandler seems to never be called.

Comment: Basically I am not clear what events should happen for the block to be called. Once it did, for inexplicable reasons, it went to the default.

Comment: Your situation seems to have changed drastically, but this is a much better question for StackOverflow than you originally posted. Have you tried logging the value of `state` inside your handler? it might be that you're getting some events but not the ones you're looking for (perhaps your match contains only a single player?).

Comment: The problem is that the block has never been called again since I posted my latest update. I am really not sure about what triggers it. I tried opening the app, shouting etc. but nothing happened. The invitation on its part arrives _most_ times. Also, what should I do on the receiving app? The GKSession found in the books is obsolete.

Comment: While I can't help you with the specifics, this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/4771121/1180785 seems to have found a working example of using GKVoiceChat (2) which can perhaps help you (and the links aren't dead yet)

Comment: Thanks, but, first off, that posting refers to iOS 4 when perhaps GKVoiceChatService was still usable, and more specifically, it refers to organizing a pong multiplayer game and the link is a list of people asking for a tutorial with no one offering it. At any rate Apple is quite clear, but by following their advice the connection is not established. More specifically I do not know what to do on the receiving end given class GKVoiceChatService is obsolete.

Comment: As a matter of fact the problem was that the GKVoiceChat is autoreleased and so it was lost in the block. Notwithstanding when I attach to a strong property I have a crash instead.

Comment: The crash reports: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' but, of course I have no insert nor array in the block.

Comment: It looks like the start method produces the crash, since if I comment it no crash ensues. What could be wrong in the configuration producing the crash in that function?